# Combine two unioned tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have two tables that look something like this. One has "package" data and the other has "recipe" data.

```
Order#   Lot#    Pkg#  Time
----------------------------
188688   PVB079   19   2:34
188688   PVB079   24   3:15
188688   PVB079   18   4:08
188688   PVB079   13   5:02
188688   PVB079   14   5:40
188688   PVB079   16   6:18
188688   PVB079   15   6:48
188688   PVB079   21   7:22
188688   PVB079   17   8:12
```

```
Order#  Recipe  Version  Time
------------------------------
188688  EP01     1       2:35
188688  EP01     2       4:09
188688  EP01     3       6:49
```

I can UNION them together and order it by the timestamp to get something that looks like this...

```
Order#   Lot#    Pkg#  Time  Recipe   Version
----------------------------------------------
188688   PVB079   19   2:34   --        --
188688    --      --   2:35   EP01      1
188688   PVB079   24   3:15   --        --
188688   PVB079   18   4:08   --        -- 
188688    --      --   4:09   EP01      2
188688   PVB079   13   5:02   --        --
188688   PVB079   14   5:40   --        --
188688   PVB079   16   6:18   --        --
188688   PVB079   15   6:48   --        --
188688    --      --   6:49   EP01      3
188688   PVB079   21   7:22   --        --
188688   PVB079   17   8:12   --        --
```

However, I would like to combine them so that the recipe data is in the same row as the 1 package before it, and the other packages after it.  My ideal result would look something like this...

```
Order#   Lot#    Pkg#  PkgTime  Recipe   Version   RecipeTime
---------------------------------------------------------------
188688   PVB079   19   2:34     EP01      1        2:35
188688   PVB079   24   3:15     EP01      1        2:35
188688   PVB079   18   4:08     EP01      2        4:09 
188688   PVB079   13   5:02     EP02      2        4:09
188688   PVB079   14   5:40     EP02      2        4:09
188688   PVB079   16   6:18     EP02      2        4:09
188688   PVB079   15   6:48     EP02      3        6:49
188688   PVB079   21   7:22     EP02      3        6:49
188688   PVB079   17   8:12     EP02      3        6:49
```

Operationally, a package is entered (timestamp) and then they get a recipe (timestamp).  But sometimes the recipe doesn't change. Therefore, they use the same recipe for the following packages until the recipe changes.

Is that possible?  How can I combine these two tables like this?

Comment: `JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` may be helpful terms to look up.  It's a bit like `UNION` but for results that can be correlated together somehow.  (that is they have some formulaic relationship that can be easily expressed)

Comment: This is the UNION query that results in table #3 above...
`SELECT sf_ord_no, mfg_lot_number, package_number, time_stamp, '' AS recipe_used, 0 AS revision_used  FROM tblSFD_Expander_Material WHERE package_number <> 0   and sf_ord_no = '  188688' UNION SELECT sf_ord_no, '', 0, time_stamp, recipe_used, revision_used FROM tblSFD_Recipes_Used  WHERE sf_ord_no = '  188688'  ORDER BY time_stamp`

Comment: A  JOIN would give me 27 rows instead of 9.  The issue here is that the formulaic relationship is not easily expressed.

Comment: @Bruno71 You'd really only get 27 rows back if used `CROSS JOIN` or an uncorrelated `JOIN`.  If you choose a relationship with `ON` correctly, you'll limit that set down to something less.  And in this case, you'll also probably want `GROUP BY` since you're trying to choose "best" data from among several rows which `MIN` and `MAX` can do.  Note: The correlations here are weak and you may want to consider database redesign or better understanding the relationships.

Comment: Yes, I understand JOIN and ON and GROUP BY.  And I agree that the correlations are weak, but it's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gordon Linoff answer, this seems to match your question

```
select p.*, r.*
from package p 
outer apply
  (select top (1) r.*
   from recipe r
   where r.rec_order = p.pkg_order and r.rec_time < isnull((
     select min(p2.pkg_time)
     from package p2
     where p2.pkg_order = p.pkg_order and p2.pkg_time > p.pkg_time       
     ), convert(datetime2, '9999-12-31'))
   order by r.rec_time desc
  ) r
order by pkg_time
```

Comment: Thanks Antonin.  I think this might work!  My initial test with it returns a result just like my ideal table above.  I will explore it further, but this should be a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `union`.  You can most easily do it using a lateral join, which in SQL Server uses `apply`:

```
select p.*, r.*
from package p outer apply
     (select top (1) r.*
      from recipe r
      where r.order# = p.order# and r.time > p.time
      order by r.time asc
     ) r;
```

A lateral join is like a correlated subquery that can return multiple columns and multiple rows (although in this case, it is only returning one row).

Comment: I'm not sure why a regular `JOIN` wouldn't work in this case?  Why the need for vendor-specific features?  (Okay I see why `OUTER` but why use `APPLY` instead of `JOIN`?)

Comment: @ebyrob . . . How would you choose one row in `recipe` per row in `package` using a `join`?

Comment: This was close...but the problem is that the recipe time is not always greater than the package time.  Look at my table #4 above.  A package will use the previous recipe until the recipe changes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  package.`Order#`,
  package.`Lot#`,
  package.`Pkg#`,
  package.`Time` AS PkgTime,
  recipe.Recipe,
  recipe.`Version`,
  recipe.`Time` AS RecipeTime
FROM (
SELECT
  p.`Order#` AS keyOrder,
  MAX(IF(p.Time < r.Time, p.Time, NULL)) AS startTime,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(p.Time < r2.Time, p.Time, NULL)), MAX(p.Time)+1 ) AS endTime,
  r.`Version` AS keyRecipeVersion,
  r.Time AS r1t,
  r2.Time AS r2t
FROM recipe AS r
LEFT JOIN recipe AS r2 ON r2.`Order#` = r.`Order#` AND r2.Version = 1 + r.Version
JOIN package AS p ON p.`Order#` = r.`Order#` -- all packages.  
GROUP BY p.`Order#`, r.`Version`
) AS k
JOIN recipe ON keyOrder = recipe.`Order#` AND keyRecipeVersion = recipe.`Version`
JOIN package ON keyOrder = package.`Order#` 
            AND package.`Time` >= startTime AND package.`Time` < endTime
            -- recipe start is 1 back package time.  
;
```

The idea is to distill the record you want down to one set of "key fields" that can then be re-joined back to the source tables.  In this case your indexing is weak and your data isn't well organized so it's a bit tricky and less robust.

The other answer with `OUTER APPLY` may well be more elegant, I just like to avoid non-ANSI SQL when possible.

NOTE: This could also probably be done by wrapping the `UNION` with `GROUP BY` but I definitely wouldn't recommend it.  `UNION` makes for messy inconsistent queries and is mostly for slapping something together quickly.

Comment: This resulted in something similar to the other answer. It only connects the recipe with a time greater than the package time.  Sometimes the recipe time is earlier than the package time.

Comment: @Bruno71 I have a rather in-elegant solution using standard SQL components, but I really think this one you can solve on your own.  The first step is you need to create a single row of data that includes the recipe "unique key" columns along with the order number and the min/max values of package Time that are acceptable.  From there it's a strait re-JOIN to both package and recipe using the established key fields.  My solution here fails because it doesn't JOIN recipe to itself which I think is required since your requirements depend on knowing "next recipe" information.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about elegance. :-) You mentioned getting the min/max values of package times.  With a given recipe time, how can I get all the package times up to but not including the package time before the next recipe time?

Comment: I give up, I've pasted my complete query in above.  This is just an example.  It can be made more robust if the assumptions don't match your data.  Bottom line, SQL isn't very good at manipulating this kind of "chained" data relationship.  You're likely better off using temporary tables to break operations into smaller pieces or using SQL loops and conditionals to just copy standard procedural techniques.   (Or, my favorite, don't do it in SQL at all, only use SQL to retrieve raw data do the logical work in a real programming language)